# gRPC response streaming with repeated field in Python

Tags: python, streaming, grpc

I am currently designing an API that is supposed to handle **relatively small messages but many data entries**. There are operations to add, delete and **list all items** stored in a database.

Now to my question: I want to return **all entries** (up to 5 Million) in a short amount of time. I figured response streaming would be the way to go.

Does it make sense to **stream messages with a repeated field** to be able to return **multiple entries in one message**. So far i haven't seen any indication whether that is faster or not.

Example:

```
rpc ListDataSet (ListDataSetRequest) returns (stream ListDataSetResponse);


message ListDataSetResponse {
  string transaction_id = 1;
  repeated Entries entries = 2;
}
```

And in the server i would **append a certain amount of entries to each message and yield the messages** while looping over the list of entries to use a generator.

Any recommendations or tips would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes sense to stream messages containing repeated fields.

From a performance perspective, you may want to consider benchmarking your alternatives to prove this to yourself.

gRPC lacks comprehensive best practices but one reads that smaller messages are better and 4MiB is often given as a good, notional upper bound.

One other thing to consider is that it's not just the performance of your servers but also of your clients that you need to consider.

A more common pattern (?) is to page large results and give control to the client to ask for next|other pages. This may be worth evaluating too.

For exceptionally "huge" (unspecified) results, you'd likely be better placed returning a reference in your gRPC message to an out-of-band (e.g. object storage) object.